# How do I permanentely disable Google Analytics Tracking on my page?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I use Google Analytics on my page, and I want to give the user the option to disable the tracking by clicking on a button that executes the following code:

```
window["ga-disable-<my tracking id>"] = true;
```

This code is provided by Google: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-opt-out

However, it sets the property and doesen't send any more hit tasks as long as I stay in the session, but as soon as I reload the page the property is set to false again.

Is there any way I can disable it permanentely?

Comment: Try  to save  it in a cookie,then you read the value in the cookie when the page reloads. Another options could be the html5 localStorage, but I don't know if it persists in a page reload

Comment: See: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom function will need to be execute. It will set a cookie for a long time in the future and disable analytics.js data collection. When a user returns to this site, the script above will check to see if the opt-out cookie has been set. If it has, then the analytics.js data collection will also be disabled.
For reference use the below URL

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#disable